# Copy SQL Server database between two servers

Tags: sql-server

I have a productive SQL Server database on one server. Also on this server there are the databases for test and development, which was over a long period no big deal for performance. But now I have to test some quite expensive selects for a nightly report and so my users get heavy trouble using the database during working hours.

We have a redundant server with SQL Server running which we never really used, but now we think his time has come. Until now, to get a fresh copy of the production system I do a full backup, copy it into a folder on Server A and connect the folder as network drive an Server B. Then I copy the file into a folder where SQL Server has read permissions and import the backup into the database on B.

On Server A I have made some maintenance plans for backing up the production system into one of the other systems by executing the plan.

I want some solution like this for my B Server, but it doesn't seem to get running. I can do a Select from server A in a table on server B, so they both do know each other and can see them.

I've tried the copy database wizard but it crashes because it couldn't delete the database on server B even if I had removed it manually before the try.

I also tried importing the Database on Server B from Server A but it didn't work either.

Googling my problem didn't work out because I always get solutions to the problem making backup files onto some kind of server.

Hope someone of you could help automating this process.

Comment: So why do you not use the "other system" for your needs? That would do two very important things. First, it would validate your disaster recovery methodology (which you should have documented somewhere). It would also allow you to test non-destructive queries in an environment that is completely separate from your production system. FWIW it is a significant risk to run both production and development (and likely test) databases within the same instance.

Comment: And make life simpler. Create a network share for the files that your server instances need to access rather than define a user-based share every time this is needed. Give that share the appropriate permissions so your instances can access it as needed. After that, you only need to backup the source database to the share and then restore the target database from the same share.

Comment: Hi, I don't use the other system because I'm not the one who has to dicide which system could be used. I also can not create a share because I want to so I have to find a solution with the rights I have.